# Android: Not receiving the extra intent ID

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I'm trying to send data from a textview to another activity but in the destination activity it doesn't pick up the extra intent data ID. To clarify, in the destination activity it does not recognize the variable "username" . How do i fix this?

MainActivity activity (sender)

```
public  final static String username = "com.example.eugen.test.MainActivity.etUsername";

 Intent destination_intent = new Intent(this, destination.class);
            destination_intent.putExtra(username,etUsername.getText());
            startActivity(destination_intent);
```

Destination activity

```
String usernameReceived = null;
usernameReceived = getIntent().getStringExtra(destination.username);
```

Comment: whats your source activity name ? and is username declared in that activity ?

Comment: MainActivity is the source activity name. I declared it yep

Comment: then in your destination activity you should write `MainActivity.username`

Comment: Man my brain is the worst! That fixed it. Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: glad to help :), posting it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `destination.username` to `MainActivity.username` as your variable `username` is declared as `static` in `MainActivity`. And as Ivan V suggested, its always a good practice to create a `Constants` file and declare your `static` `constants` there, it will make things more cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one single key, for example "userName" both when you put extras and when you get extras.

```
Intent destination_intent = new Intent(this, destination.class);
            destination_intent.putExtra("userName",etUsername.getText());
            startActivity(destination_intent);
```

Then in destination class

```
String usernameReceived = null;
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null) {
    usernameReceived = getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");

}
```

I suggest you to create separate Constants class and place your

```
public  final static String username = "com.example.eugen.test.MainActivity.etUsername";
```

there. And then you can access it via Constants.username from any other class

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

you have not get correct method, you get like this

```
        Intent destination_intent = new Intent(this, destination.class);
        destination_intent.putExtra("userName",etUsername.getText());
        startActivity(destination_intent);
```

Then in destination class

```
    String usernameReceived = null;
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     if(intent != null) {
  usernameReceived = getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");

    }
```